# Get specific data from Firestore and convert it to string, int, ... variables

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating this post as I can't solve my problem with existing ones.

I'm saving the current time on Firestore with :

```
Map<String, Object> docData = new HashMap<>();
            docData.put("Starting date", new Timestamp(new Date()).toDate());
            docData.put("Quantification", 3.14569);


            userManager.getUsersCollection().document(userManager.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                    .collection("habits")
                    .document(selectedHabit)
                    .set(docData)
```

Then, I would like to get back the timestamp and use it to count since how many days it's been created. I'm stuck here. The only way I found to access specific data of a document is by doing this :

```
userManager.getLoggedUserHabitsSubCollection()
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < QuerySnapshot > () {@
        Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < QuerySnapshot > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document: task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d("test", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData() + " => " + document.get("Starting date"));
                }
            } else {}
        }
    });
```

with "document.get("Starting date") I can access my saved date, that's the only thing that I was able to make work to do so. Now I would like to be able to display this Object in a string, and to check differences between dates to know how much time have passed. And here I'm stuck. I see a lot of different answers on forums, like using .toDate() for example, but when I write document.getData().toDate(), it's in red. I tried a lot of things with different ways of writing it, it's always in red and I can't make it work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see a lot of different answers on forums, like using .toDate() for example, but when I write document.getData().toDate(), it's in red.

[DocumentSnapshot#getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()) method returns an object of type `Map<String, Object>`. So there is no way you can add a call to `.toDate()` on such an object. If you need to get the value of a specific field as a [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, then you should use the [getDate(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getDate(java.lang.String)) method, which:

> Returns the value of the field as a Date.

Or [DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp(String field)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getTimestamp(java.lang.String)) method which:

> Returns the value of the field as a com.google.firebase.Timestamp.

Once you have the Date object, you can then [calculate the difference between two Java date instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances).

Comment: Thanks it might sounds silly but I was confused about this, your answer help me I finally used "document.getTimestamp("myString")" to make it work, had no idea of this "getDate" or "getTimestamp" feature

Comment: Good to hear that you made it work.